# Programmatically transitioning to new view controller on rotation to landscape, and transitioning back on rotate to landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

Hey everyone and thanks in advance for the help.

I'm working on a new project that's iPad only. It is intended to start in a portrait-orientation view controller, then transition to a different landscape view controller on rotation to landscape mode. I would then like to be able to transition back to the portrait view controller in the state that it was in before rotation when rotated back.

All elements of both views are currently laid out programmatically, the only thing in my interface builder is an instance of the initial portrait view controller left blank.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Why not use size classes and Auto Layout in the storyboard instead of two view controllers?

Comment: Because it's an iPad exclusive app so size classes are the same between portrait and landscape, and it needs to pass data between the two controllers on transition since the two controllers serve different functions using some common data that is changed by both viewcontrollers.

I figured it out anyway by using a UIDeviceOrientationDidChange notification and calling a segue in an orientationChanged method, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Good explanation. I haven't built apps for iPad and didn't realize size classes were the same in both orientations.